# Justification for the conjectures on self-avoiding walks

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk, conjectures

There are two conjectures on self-avoiding walks that I haven't seen any justification of. One is the asymptotic growth of the number of length $n$ self-avoiding walks, the form I've seen most often is $$ c_n \sim A\mu^n n^{\gamma-1}, $$

where $A, \mu, \gamma$ are constants. Of all the literature I've seen, I haven't read about any justification for this formula, rigorous or not.

The other conjecture is stated in the Wikipedia page for self-avoiding walks and says that finding the number of such walks in a given lattice is NP-hard. There was no citation given for this, so I must ask where does this assertion appear in the literature.

Edit: Any papers referencing the NP-hardness conjecture should be about counting SAWs in the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$ or $\mathbb{Z}^n$

Comment: Where do these walks take place? On a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^2$? $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Let's say $\mathbb{Z}^2$, if not $\mathbb{Z}^n$ in general.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-AvoidingWalkConnectiveConstant.html

On that page, look at equation $(12)$. The citation given is "Madras, N. and Slade, G. The Self-Avoiding Walk. Boston, MA: Birkhäuser, 1993."

Comment: See also equation $(3.1)$ here: https://www.math.ubc.ca/~slade/spa_proceedings.pdf